# How to Buffer with intersections in QGIS

Tags: qgis, buffer

I am buffering a layer of facilities (points). I will then use the buffer to clip and intersect another layer, containing resources.

I want to answer the question, how much of the resource lies within X distance of the facility?

Buffer facility -> clip resource so only areas within buffer remain -> intersect facility buffer and resource to show amount of resource within distance of facility.

Now, I am using ftools to create my buffer. The problem is, when the facilities are already within X distance of each other it does not create a full circular buffer, the polygons created do not overlap.

How can I create a buffer in QGIS where the polygons of the buffer are allowed to overlap each other (possible in ArcGIS)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you leave the "Dissolve buffer results" unticked it should work fine

[image]

Comment: Thank you I am just being a fool... I did try this, but when I selected the resulting buffers they do not select as circular so I assumed it hadn't worked. When I change the style to transparent I can see that it has. A QGIS / ArcMap selection variation in the interface.